# Creating Firebird Connection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, firebird

I am new to Firebird. I installed Firebird 2.5  and when I want to create a connection in Visual studio 2010 .net the Connection form reject. And I can't type any word in this form.

Comment: There's no Firebird "2.7", [the latest is 2.5.1 October 4, 2011 as of 01/2012](http://firebirdsql.org/). What is your question? - Ah, you're referring to the ADO.NET Provider for Firebird, which is at 2.7 indeed.

Comment: oh you are right i install Firebird-2.5.1.26351 and when i want to create a connection in Visual studio 2010 the Creation form reject and i cant type any thing in that form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't bother with the wizard (maybe not supported) and [provide the connection string yourself](http://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird).